# acces data in a static way Java

Tags: java, static, http-headers, sonarqube

Hi I'm doing something like this

```
String app = (String) getRequestHeader().getHeaderParameter(RequestHeaderParamsName.HEADERNAME.AAP);
String chan = (String) getRequestHeader().getHeaderParameter(RequestHeaderParamsName.HEADERNAME.CHANNELCODE);
```

But SonarQube throws the next exception

> Change this instance-reference to a static reference.

In eclipse I'm using the sonarlint plugin, and says this:

> The static field RequestHeaderParamsName.AAP should be accessed in a static way

and this one too

> The static field RequestHeaderParamsName.CHANNELCODE should be accessed in a static way

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could just delete `.HEADERNAME`

```
String app = (String) getRequestHeader().getHeaderParameter(RequestHeaderParamsName.AAP);
```

From the message it looks as if `RequestHeaderParamsName.HEADERNAME` is a static field of type `RequestHeaderParamsName`, and that `RequestHeaderParamsName.AAP` is also a static field, presumably of type `String`.